# What is considered as parameters/coefficients/weights?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model

I am doing lesson 2 of the fast-ai course, and I find myself with a doubt about the course.

Are the weights/parameters only *the slope and the cut of axis y* of a simple linear function $y = ax+b$?

[image]

Or what is really a weight ?

Answer (score 3):

Parameters of the model that you describe are indeed only $a$ (*slope*) and $b$ (*intercept*). Other, more complicated models, have other parameters. By *training* (*fitting*) of the model you mean finding the values of these parameters that make the model explain your data (in the sense of minimizing some objective function).

Parameters of the model can be sometimes called also *weights*, for example, in the context of neural networks, this is usually the case.

Answer (score 1):

When the coefficients are themselves variables, they may also be called parameters.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient